# setRotation method for QGraphicsSimpleTextItem() slow zommig and pannig interaction

Tags: pyqt5, qgraphicsview

I have a GUI that show line and text aligned to each line, I use QGraphicsSimpleTextItem() for text.

**Issue:**

If there is no Rotation method used on QGraphicsSimpleTextItem() zoom and pan (subclass QGraphcisView) interaction runs rapidly, but if a Rotation is assigned to those items text zoom and pan interaction becomes very slow.

**Question:**

I have Line Profiler to find the line that consumes more time in the class, but nothing really stands out, as shown below. Is there any reason this would happen? How can I improve this?

**Setting text rotation (ang)**
[image]

**Commenting out text rotation line (ang)**
[image]

Per Hit time does not show a great increase or decrease but the user experience regarding zoom and pan interaction when commenting line  # dict_Text[str(i)].setRotation(ang[i]) is very different.

**Reproduce Problem:**

Below is a code that reproduces the trouble I am experiencing, first run the code as is an you will have a very slow zoom and pan interaction, then comment out the line dict_Text[str(i)].setRotation(ang[i]) and zoom and pan interaction will be very fast.

**Code:**

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
import numpy as np
import sys
print(QtCore.PYQT_VERSION_STR)

class GraphicsView(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    @profile
    def __init__(self, scene, parent):
        super(GraphicsView, self).__init__(scene, parent)

        #Mouse Tracking
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        #Zoom Anchor
        self.setTransformationAnchor(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setResizeAnchor(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        #Antialiasing and indexing
        self.setRenderHints(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing | QtGui.QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing | QtGui.QPainter.TextAntialiasing)
        self.setCacheMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.CacheBackground)
        self.resetCachedContent()
        scene.setItemIndexMethod(QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene.NoIndex)

        #Pan variable
        self.pos_init_class = None

    @profile
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        pos = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
        #Mouse Pan
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.MiddleButton:
            self.pos_init_class = pos
        super(GraphicsView, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    @profile
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if self.pos_init_class and event.button() == QtCore.Qt.MiddleButton:
            #Mouse Pan
            self.pos_init_class = None
        super(GraphicsView, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)

    @profile
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.pos_init_class:
            #Mouse Pan
            delta = self.pos_init_class - self.mapToScene(event.pos())
            r = self.mapToScene(self.viewport().rect()).boundingRect()
            self.setSceneRect(r.translated(delta))
        super(GraphicsView, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)

    @profile
    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        #Mouse Zoom
        if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
            self.scale(1.5, 1.5)
        else:
            self.scale(1 / 1.5, 1 / 1.5)


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui_MainWindow, self).__init__()


    def plt_plot(self):
        #Create data set
        size = 200
        x = np.random.randint(0, high=1000, size=size, dtype=int)
        y = np.random.randint(0, high=1000, size=size, dtype=int)
        ang = np.random.randint(1, high=360, size=size, dtype=int)

        #Store Text in Dict
        dict_Text = {}

        for i in range(len(x)):
            #Create Text Item
            dict_Text[str(i)] = QtWidgets.QGraphicsSimpleTextItem()

            #Set text
            dict_Text[str(i)].setText('nn-mm \nL: 50.6 m \nD: 1500 mm')

            #Set Pos
            dict_Text[str(i)].setPos(x[i], y[i])

            #Set rotation angle
            dict_Text[str(i)].setRotation(ang[i])

            #Add to Scene
            self.graphicsView.scene().addItem(dict_Text[str(i)])


    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        #Central Widget
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        main_width, main_heigth = 1200, 800
        MainWindow.resize(main_width, main_heigth)

        #Create GraphicsView and Scene
        self.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
        self.graphicsView = GraphicsView(scene=self.scene, parent=self.centralwidget)

        #Set Geometry
        self.graphicsView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, main_width, main_heigth))

        #plot dummy data set
        self.plt_plot()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: With the provided code your issue is not reproducible, please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, comments should use the appripriate `#` character and in should also be in English language.

Comment: musicamante, I have edited my question with enough code and references to reproduce the problem. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the QGraphicsView framework documentations states that it's pretty fast, that doesn't mean that it's *always* fast.

The rendering speed depends on many factors, and *individual item transformation* can drastically decrease the overall performance.

Consider that the drawing of **all** items is done as *individual* raster painting (the backend is almost all Qt's own rendering: its optimization, while normally good, is not perfect).
For each item that has an individual transformation, the painter will need to do the painting based on *that* transformation.
If you have 200 items, each one with its own transformation, that means a *lot* of computing.

Note: a transformation is a [matrix](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtransform.html#details) that can transform the painting (meaning that *everything* will need special and additional computation).
Qt transformations pretty standard:

- translation
- scale
- [shear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_mapping)
- [projection]
- rotation (which is done by combining shearing and scaling, hence the complexity)
- perspective (which is done by combining projection and scaling)

Then you have to add the fact that you're not drawing simple items, but *text based items*. Text painting requires *a lot* of computation, despite all the optimization that Qt and the underlying system provide.

I wouldn't go into deep on how text painting is done, but you have to consider a moltitude of aspects; let's just consider a *very few* of them:

- each letter is composed of many complex polygons (many of them using bezier curves)
- each letter has different sizes and spacings, including per-letter (and per letter-pair) spacing, also known as kerning
- some fonts have even more advanced features, like [ligature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_ligature)
- even simple alignment has to be taken into account, possibly according to the [system](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#layoutDirection-prop), [widget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#layoutDirection-prop) or even [text option](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextoption.html#setTextDirection) layout direction
- lots of other things...

Consider this (it doesn't work exactly like this, but that's just for the sake of the example): in your text you have about 20 drawable characters.
Imagine every character as an individual *newly* created instance of QPainterPath, containing *lots* of lines and bezier curves (as almost any characters does).  That's about 4000 individual paths with their own curves, each one created **every time** they are drawn.
**Then** you need to also apply a transformation matrix, due to the rotation (as explained before, *both* shear *and* translation).

I need to remark that the above is an *over*-simplification of how text drawing is done (as Qt also partially relies on the underlying system font rendering).

So, is there a solution?
Well, "not really" and "not always".

First of all, instead of using `setSceneRect()`, you could get some slight improvement by scrolling the contents of the scene. This is done by setting a (very much) bigger sceneRect and hiding the scrollbars using `set<Orientation>ScrollBarPolicy` to `ScrollBarAlwaysOff`, then moving the visible area by setting the delta position on the scroll bar values. Moving the scroll bars will just cause the repainting of the viewport, while `setSceneRect()` also requires (recursive) computation of the visible area based on the transformation *and* the scroll bar sizes.

Then, there is the OpenGL alternative, which might improve [performance](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html#performance):

> In order to accurately and quickly apply transformations and effects to items, Graphics View is built with the assumption that the user's hardware is able to provide reasonable performance for floating point instructions.
> [...]
> As a result, certain kinds of effects may be slower than expected on certain devices. It may be possible to compensate for this performance hit by making optimizations in other areas; for example, by using OpenGL to render a scene.

See [OpenGL Rendering](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html#opengl-rendering) about that, but consider that it does *not* always guarantee better performances.

Finally, if you need to show that many individual text items, each one with its own rotation, you *must* expect that performance will drastically decrease. The only possible alternative is to try to render those text items as (bigger) images, and then use QGraphicsPixmapItem, but in order to get reliable results (as bitmap based objects are prone to aliasing when transformed) you'd need to use bigger sizes for each item.

Comment: Thanks, musicamante I will give a try, if I get some result I will post it back in case someone else could use  it.